# "mvn clean install" unable to resolve junit imports

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot-test

I had written a JUnit test case for a Service class in Spring Boot web application.
I have spring-boot-starter-test in my pom.xml but when I run "mvn clean install" the junit related imports are not resolving. The error is as below.

cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Before
[ERROR]   location: package org.junit

maven build is failing with this error.

When I run build project in eclipse it is working fine as I've added the junit library in project build path. but maven build is failing.

Comment: Message is clear. There is not a class Before in dependency which you are using. Check if version of that dependency has that class. Maybe you want to use junit 4 but your dependency is for junit5

Comment: I'm also getting the below error..
"cannot find symbol class Test"

But I believe @Test is available in spring-boot-starter-test.

Comment: You are saying that it happens only with maven... so just analyze log better, use debugging flag like : "mvn clean install -X". You can see everything what maven is doing, Which repository it uses, what exact dependency it downloads and so on

Comment: I have excluded junit from spring-boot-starter-test and added dependency for junit-4 and mockito. Thia fixed the issue. Thank you helping.